# BackColor of ListView ColumnHeaders

Tags: listview, columnheader, backcolor

Is there a way to set the BackColor of the ColumnHeaders of a ListView?

Comment: I think based on the answers below, the answer is that there is no easy way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about Windows here. AFAIK, the header background color is determined by the system, as the ListView is a common control.

You might be able to owner-draw the header. If you're using .NET, there's a `DrawColumnHeader` event that you might want to implement, but you'd have to owner draw the entire control (i.e. the items as well).

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the [WM_CTLCOLOR](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/32685) message, now since I don't know what are you using (MFC, C#) I cannot give you any more details.

For C# take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/customheader.aspx) *(CodeProject: Customizing the header control in a ListView)*

Comment: I'm using VB, but a C# answer will also do.